# Telegram Bot delete sent photos?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am looking to delete a photo sent by my bot (`reply_photo()`), I can't find any specific reference to doing so in the documentation, and have tried `delete_message()`, but don't know how to delete a photo. Is it currently possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's currently possible in Telegram API, not the Bot API unfortunately. It's a shame :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround (that I am currently still playing with). I named the photo I sent, then when I want to delete it, I delete it using .delete(). For example:

```py
photo = x.message.reply_photo(...)
...
...
photo.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `chat_id` and the `message_id` of that message sent by bot, then you can delete using `context.bot.delete_message(chat_id, message_id)`.

Note: Bot cannot delete a message if it was sent more than 48 hours ago.